# Snippet plugin for MacVim does not working

Tags: macos, vim, vim-plugin, macvim

I installed UltiSnips plugin on MacVim using vundle. Below is .vimrc

```
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.

"Plugin 'sirver/ultisnips'

" Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
"Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
"let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
"let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
"let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
"let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
"
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
```

Installation looked fine, but when I try to run command `:UltiSnipsEdit`, it returns error 'E492: Not an editor command: UltiSnipsEdit`.

EDIT:
I mistakenly commented the line to install UltiSnips. I installed UltiSnips again and try :UltiSnipsEdit command again. Instead, I got this error message:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/arya/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
line    7:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 import vim
line    8:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 from UltiSnips import UltiSnips_Manager
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#Edit:
line    6:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     py3 vim.command("let file = '%s'" % UltiSnips_Manager._file_to_edit(vim.eval("type"), vim.eval('a:bang')))
```

What might be the problem here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin is not installed because this line is commented:

```
"Plugin 'sirver/ultisnips'
```

Comment: you are correct, i uncommented it and run :PluginInstall again. 
I got another error when run :UltiSnipsEdit. I will add the error message in my question.

Comment: Your initial problem is solved so you are supposed to mark the question as answered. Now you have another problem and thus should ask a separate question.

Comment: I am sorry I will create new question for that.